# Python DataFrame to only have one column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have below text content that has been added to a Python DataFrame:

```
                                                    0  1
0                                      Invoice Number   
1   Strahse Road 24                               ...   
2   Bahnhofstrasse 40                             ...  
3   Page 1 /                                      ...  2
```

I am only interested in having **one** column for the entire text content.

Below is the method, I am using to add the text content to the dataframe:

```py
import pandas as pd
import io

def textToDataFrame(textContent):
    return pd.read_fwf(io.StringIO(textContent), header=None, na_filter=False)
```

And this is how I get the above output:

```py
dataframe = textToDataFrame(text)
print(dataframe)
```

I am a bit unsure on how I can do so I only end up with one (0) column? The number of columns can vary dynamically, depending on the `textContent`

Comment: What kind of object exactly is `textContent`?

Comment: @Xukrao `textContent` is simply just a `string`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd

textContent = """Computer enthusiasts and power users, ask on Super User.
Professional system and network administrators, ask on Server Fault.
Users of TeX, LaTeX, ConTeXt, and related typesetting systems, ask on TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange.
Database administrators and professionals, ask on Database Administrators Stack Exchange.
SharePoint enthusiasts, ask on SharePoint Stack Exchange."""

df = pd.DataFrame(textContent.split("\n"))
print(df)
```

gives the result:

```
                                                   0
0  Computer enthusiasts and power users, ask on S...
1  Professional system and network administrators...
2  Users of TeX, LaTeX, ConTeXt, and related type...
3  Database administrators and professionals, ask...
4  SharePoint enthusiasts, ask on SharePoint Stac...
```